# filter spark dataframe based on maximum value of a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do something like this:

```
df
.withColumn("newCol", <some formula>)
.filter(s"""newCol > ${(math.min(max("newCol").asInstanceOf[Double],10))}""")
```

Exception I'm getting:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.Column cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

Can you please suggest me a way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 5):

I assume `newCol` is already present in `df`, then:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window   
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df
.withColumn("max_newCol",max($"newCol").over(Window.partitionBy()))
.filter($"newCol"> least($"max_newCol",lit(10.0)))
```

Instead of `max($"newCol").over(Window.partitionBy())` you can also jjst write `max($"newCol").over()`

Comment: It says I require a hiveContext to use the Window function

Comment: @PrathamSolanki Yes it requires a HiveContext. If this is a problem, then calculate max_newCol using groupBy and join on original dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I think dataframe [describe function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@describe(cols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) is what you are looking for.

```
ds.describe("age", "height").show()

// output:  
// summary age   height  
// count   10.0  10.0  
// mean    53.3  178.05  
// stddev  11.6  15.7  
// min     18.0  163.0  
// max     92.0  192.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate both steps and either:

```
val newDF = df
 .withColumn("newCol", <some formula>)

// Spark 2.1 or later
// With 1.x use join
newDf.alias("l").crossJoin(
  newDf.alias("r")).where($"l.newCol" > least($"r.newCol", lit(10.0)))
```

or

```
newDf.where(
  $"newCol" > (newDf.select(max($"newCol")).as[Double].first min 10.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is two parts,

Part I 
Find the maximum value,
`df.select(max($"col1")).first()(0)`

Part II 
Use that value to filter on it 
`df.filter($"col1" === df.select(max($"col1")).first()(0)).show`

Bonus 
To avoid potential errors, you can also get the maximum value in a specific format you need, using the `.get` family on it `df.select(max($"col1")).first.getDouble(0)` 
In this case `col1` is DoubleType, so I chose to pick it in the correct format. You can get pretty much all other types. Options are: 
getBoolean, getClass, getDecimal, getFloat, getJavaMap, getLong, getSeq, getString, getTimestamp, getAs, getByte, getDate, getDouble, getInt, getList, getMap, getShort, getStruct, getValuesMap 
Making the full solution in this case 
`df.filter($"col1" === df.select(max($"col1")).first.getDouble(0)).show`