# How to drop first row from parquet file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I have parquet file which contain two columns(id,feature).file consists of 14348 row.[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf7wD.jpg)
How i drop first row id,feature from file

code

```
val df = spark.read.format("parquet").load("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet")
val header = df.first() 
val data   = df.filter(row => row != header) 
data .show()
```

result seems as [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifJuy.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to "ignore" the schema defined in the file, it is implicitly done once you read your file, using spark like:

```
spark.read.format("parquet").load(your_file)
```

If you are trying to only skip the first row on your `DF` and if you already know the `id` you can do: `val filteredDF = originalDF.filter(s"id != '${excludeID}' ")`. If you don't know the id, you can use `monotonically_increasing_id` to tag it and then filter, similar like: [filter spark dataframe based on maximum value of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45875281/filter-spark-dataframe-based-on-maximum-value-of-a-column)

Comment: I need to drop row not to load my data only.

Comment: Drop row? Meaning remove from the datasource file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop the first row based on id if you know that, else go for indexing approach i.e., assigning the row number and delete the first row.

Comment: more details ,please.@Ruthika jawar

Comment: if you know that id whose row needs to be dropped, please go for df = df.filter("id"===somevalue) else you need to assign index column with row number and delete the first row and then delete the index column. Let me know if you know id value or wanted to assign index column so that i can help you further.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Spark `2.4.0`, and you could use the **header option** to the `DataFrameReader` call like so -

`spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).load(<path_to_file>)`

Reference for the other options for `DataFrameReader` are [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html)

Comment: But error appear value option is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

Comment: @SalmaElzeheiry - the `spark` variable above is of type `SparkSession`. The call `spark.read` returns type `DataFrameReader`.

Comment: I do that but delete second row .row which contain Id,feature still appear.val df = sqlContext.read.format("parquet").load("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet")
val skipable_first_row = df.first() 
val useful_rows    = df.filter(row => row != skipable_first_row) 
useful_rows .show()
@Kevin Lawrence

Comment: `Id` and `Feature` are the headings. For example., if you do `val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", true).load(<path_to_file>)` and then do `df.show(1)` you will not see 'Id` and `Feature` - you will see the first row of your data!!!! And it's not `sqlContext.read` - the object should be an instance of `SparkSession`!

Comment: Please use the `.option("header", true)` - from your previous comment you haven't used it. Thanks.